# Return value from javascript promise to calling function

Tags: javascript, promise

I am working on Ionic Project and have a two functions `login()` and fetchUser(). Where `fetchUser()` get data from SQlite database and return a promise.

```
fetchUser(storage){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        storage.get('user')
        .then((user) => {
            if(user != null){
                resolve(user);
             }
           })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    })
}
```

And login funciton is like this.

```
login(){
         this.fetchUser(this._storage)
             .then(user => {return user;})
             .catch(err => console.log(err));

// I want user data here
    }
```

Everything is working fine, data is fetching successfully. 
Now the problem is I want to return user (data) to `login()` function. If I call `login()` it returns `undefined`. I think this is because I an returning value from then function.

But If I log user in console in `then()` function then it is logging successfully. however it is not returning to the login function.

Comment: It seems you don't need to manually create promises since `storage.get` already returns one. http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/